# Securing a threaded thermowell into a bucket lid

Tags: temperature-probe, bucket-heater

I perhaps may have made an oops and I bought [this](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00JSYNN80) thermowell, thinking it would be *easier* to secure it to the lid than the regular straight walled one that everyone puts in a dual stopper. I thought to myself, "how does that thing stay in the hole, wouldn't the pressure work it outwards?" (a bit more of research here would have done me wonders..) Also I have one of the famed ds18b20 sensors, I got this one with a bit extra diameter to accommodate the probe. At least that's working for me...

Anyway. I have my purchase and I am attempting to affix it to the bucket lid but it's turning out to be harder than I thought.

The latest thought is a [PVC bushing](http://www.lowes.com/pd_51323-1815-439130RMC_0__?productId=3373008&Ntt=1%2F2%22%20pvc%20bushing&pl=1&currentURL=%3FNtt%3D1%252F2%2522%2Bpvc%2Bbushing&facetInfo=) and a [Nut](http://www.homedepot.com/b/Plumbing-Pipes-Fittings-PVC-Pipe-Fittings/Nut/N-5yc1vZbuf5Z1z114wo) (Whatever size I can make match) I was also looking for a gasket but I feel like I'm veering of into over engineering territory. I was hoping for some sort of threaded flange to begin with, hopes and dreams dashed in the Lowe's plumbing aisle. This would probably be over if I had a 3d printer, but maybe I think so because I want one, but I digress.

Anyone out there have any ideas? Gasket or no gasket? I just want to be able to take it completely apart for cleaning and sanitizing reasons.

I've read a few discussions about thermowell vs tape to bucket. I'm in the thermowell camp.

Edit: [image][image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest something like the ["weldless bulkhead"](http://www.northernbrewer.com/shop/weldless-kettle-bulkhead.html) approach used for adding a port to mash-tun coolers and such. From bottom to top:

```
[thermowell] [nut] [gasket] [washer] [bucket-lid] [nut]
```

Put a 1/2 hole through the bucket lid, then use two nuts to hold it against the lid, with a gasket/washer combo to create a seal. Adjust the thermowell so there's little/no exposed threads on the inside of the bucket. Use stainless washer/nuts and food-safe gasket material.

Honestly, you probably don't even need to get an airtight seal with a bucket lid, as you probably already have tons of headspace where you won't have krausen being pressed up into the lid. Two nuts would do the trick.  Honestly, just one nut on the top would hold it in place.

Also … the thermowell was only $10. Maybe just get a better suited one and forgo a lunch out, or whatever? ;)

Comment: _Maybe just get a better suited one and forgo a lunch out, or whatever?_ It's about the principle. I ended up using a 1/2 3/4 bushing, a cap/nut that I hack sawed the cap part off of to thread the stem tighter. I also found some rubber pads and fashioned some gaskets. I think I'll take your last bit of advice after the weekend. Had a brew day scheduled and nothing would have come in, in time.

Answer (score 0):

If you can buy some appropriate plastic and epoxy (or just a bunch of epoxy), you can build up a thick spot on the lid and then drill & tap it. Drilling & tapping plastic should be easy, easier than drilling a hole in wood. Then you can just screw the thermowell into the lid as needed. And you probably won't need teflon tape either.